# Facebook sdk 3.5 publish stories not allowed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used android Facebook sdk 3.5 for my web and android application to login, and created some custom actions, problem is that I am only able to publish stories from developers account, I have my application reviewed from Facebook already, and for the reference here is an snap !

http://postimg.org/image/rhhezzpvf/

The error I get from non developer account is

04-23 11:47:43.164: I/System.out(11189): *****{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) App XXXXXXXXXXX is not allowed to create actions of type citydealweb:Avail for user XXXXXXXXXXXXX}, isFromCache:false}

Any help will be appreciated! thnx

Comment: If you're using custom actions, those actions will need to be approved as well. I didn't see that in your screenshot.

Comment: I will see to it, thank you for response